# The behaviour of the or operator in PHP

Tags: php, or-operator

I'm trying to understand the behavior of `or` operator. Please see the below examples:

```
$e = false || true;
var_dump($e);
```

Output is as expected: `bool(true);`

```
$f = false or true;
var_dump($f);
```

Output is as expected: `bool(false)`. I understood this in a way that the `=` has a higher precedence than the `Or`, so that's why the `$f` is assigned to `false`.

But the below code works quite opposite of what I thought. I thought that the `$foo` will be assigned to `5` and then compared to itself.
But the `$foo` is getting assigned only when if the `$foo` is set that means it is checking if the `$foo` is assigned to anything before, assign 5 to it.

```
$foo or $foo = 5;
```

Can anyone explain why this is so?

Comment: +1 good question. Extremely useful to future programmers for anyone who is stuck on this point.

Comment: Not directly related you might find [this page](http://codeboutique.com/tools/pvaat/pvaat.php) useful. I've thought about adding boolean operators as well.

Comment: I've updated the page to show 'or' and 'and' in different situations. There are some odd results.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The basics:

1. An assignment expression results in the assigned value.

   What does that mean? `$foo = 'bar'` is an expression, in which the assignment operator `=` assigns a value. An expression always returns a value itself. Just like the expression `1 + 2` results in the value `3`, the expression `$foo = 'bar'` results in the value `'bar'`. That's why this works:

   ```
   $foo = $bar = 'baz'; // which is: $foo = ($bar = 'baz');
   ```
2. Boolean operations are short-circuiting operations. Both sides are not always evaluated if they don't need to be. `true || false` is always `true` overall, since the lefthand operand is `true`, so the whole expression must be `true`. `false` is not even being evaluated here.
3. [Operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) dictates in which order parts of an expression are grouped into sub-expressions. Higher precedence operators are grouped with their operands before lower precedence operators.

Therefore:

> ```
> $e = false || true;
> ```

`false || true` is being evaluated, which results in the value `true`, which is assigned to `$e`. The `||` operator has a higher precedence than `=`, therefore `false || true` is grouped into an expression (as opposed to `($e = false) || true`).

> ```
> $f = false or true;
> ```

Here now `or` has a *lower* precedence than `=`, which means the assignment operation is grouped into one expression before `or`. So first the `$f = false` expression is evaluated, the result of which is `false` (see above). So then you have the simple expression `false or true` which is evaluated next and results in `true`, but which nobody cares about.

The evaluation works like this:

```
1. $f = false or true;
2. ($f = false) or true;  // precedence grouping
3. false or true;         // evaluation of left side ($f is now false)
4. true;                  // result
```

Now:

> ```
> $foo or $foo = 5;
> ```

Here, again, `$foo = 5` has a higher precedence and is treated as one expression. Since it occurs on the right side of the `or` operator, the expression is only evaluated if necessary. It depends on what `$foo` is initially. If `$foo` is `true`, the right hand side will not be evaluated at all, since `true or ($foo = 5)` must be `true` overall. If `$foo` has a falsey value initially though, the right hand side is evaluated and `5` is assigned to `$foo`, which results in `5`, which is true-ish, which means the overall expression is `true`, which nobody cares about.

```
1. $foo or $foo = 5;
2. $foo or ($foo = 5);   // precedence grouping
3. false or ($foo = 5);  // evaluation of left side
4. false or 5;           // evaluation of right side ($foo is now 5)
5. true;                 // result
```

Comment: Got it in a first move. Thanks for such a nice explanation. FYI: I got beneficial from your `charset` topic recently. Thanks

Comment: It appears that when not contrained by short-circuiting operators like `or`, PHP _does_ evaluate parenthesized expressions first, e.g. `$foo = 2; echo $foo + ($foo = 4)` will print 8, not 6. Is this actually specified in the language, or just an implementation decision?

Comment: @Barbar I'm sure you can figure out the evaluation logic behind that somehow, but I'd say that the behavior of  such self-modifying and mostly nonsensical operations are by definition mostly undefined.

Comment: @Barmar It is not documented AFAIK, but this is not mainly because of the parantheses but because for an expression A + B, PHP first evaluates A **and** B, then sums them up. Now comes the tricky part: $foo evaluates to the corresponding ZVal (variable reference) while ($foo = 4) evaluates to the *value* 4 with the side-effect of modifying $foo. *Then* they get summed up.

Comment: could you let me know when to use like `$b  or   $b = '1';` since if $b is not set than its rises [Undefined variable error](http://3v4l.org/R19Dq)

Answer (score 20):

As per the [php.net webpage about Logical Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

This:

```
$e = false || true;
```

Acts like this:

```
$e = (false || true) // If false is true, then $e = false. Otherwise true
```

This:

```
$f = false or true;
```

Would act like this:

```
($f = false) or true; // $f = false is true, as the assignment succeeded
```

This:

```
$foo or $foo = 5;
```

Would act like this:

```
$foo or ($foo = 5) // foo = undefined or foo = 5, so foo = 5
```

For the last one, undefined is basically like false, therefore foo equals 5.

Also, here's the link for the operator precedence order: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

**UPDATE:**

Ok, now let's get to the main point. Like how we all know when using a fetched query:

```
while($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

And we all know while loops only execute on `true`, therefore `$row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` returns true.

Same with Daric's question.

```
$foo or $foo = 5;
```

Is basically:

```
$foo or ($foo = 5);
```

Which is basically:

```
$foo = undefined or ($foo = 5); // $foo = 5 actually returns true
```

Which is also

```
$foo = undefined or true;
```

And as I have previously mentioned, undefined = false, so therefore $foo = 5 (as that is the true statement).

I hope everyone can understand.

Comment: *"If $f cannot be assigned, then true"* - No, rather *if the result of the expression `$f = false` is `true` or ...*. And the result of an assignment expression is the assigned value.

Comment: @deceze I would think otherwise. That was according to the PHP documentation.

Comment: Can you post the reference to that? There is no way something cannot be assigned though, the `=` operator always returns the assigned value.

Comment: @deceze Actually your explanation seems true too. I wouldn't want to continue this argument anymore. Either way, it still is roughly the same.

Comment: @think123 PHP document does point out that assignment expression "returns" the assigned result http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php . This is not "roughly the same" because `$f=true or false` will not "execute" `false` while `$f=false or true` will "execute" `true`.

Comment: if you think my code needs improving, can you please edit it? thank you very much.

Comment: @think123: Again thinking on this left me confused a totally confused, I think there is something still not clear in mind.

Comment: @Daric what is it you don't understand? I really want to help you.

Comment: @think123: If you are available can we go in the php chat system.

Comment: @Daric Oh no not now, sorry. I just finished editing my answer, It should be able to help you.

Comment: @think123: here in this statement `$foo or $foo = 5;` Why should not it first assign the `5` to `$foo` as the `=` has higher precedence than the `or`. Why not `=` evaluated first.

Comment: What? `@mysql_*`? Can't you use PDO for your example? I haven't seen `@` *and* `mysql_*` in an *answer* before.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff It's just for testing purposes, not strictly for usage.

Answer (score 3):

```
$foo or $foo = 5;

Suppose let say $foo=true or $foo=5;
```

here it will not evaluate after or operator expresion so output will be $foo=1
      Now the expression is

`$foo=false or $foo=5;`

Here it will evaluate after or as = higher precedence so `$foo` as of which of which it will evaluate `$foo=5`so output will be `5`
 But when we evaluate `$foo=false or true` so here it will consider = higher precedence so the output will be `$foo=false` but whole expression will evaluate as true because `false or true` becomes `false`

Comment: Precedence refers to grouping, not order of evaluation.  As deceze explained, `or` always evaluates its left argument first, because it's a short-circuiting operator.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$foo = false;
$foo or ($foo = '5');
echo $foo;
?>
```

Check this you can assign the value "5" for `$foo`.

Compare than `or` `=` has high priority.. Thats the fact.... :)