# Difference between 'or' and '||'?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$conn = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password) || die('Connection to mysql failed');
mysql_close($conn);
```

On executing this code, the following warning was displayed.

PHP Warning:  mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in script.php on line 45

```
$conn = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password) or die('Connection to mysql failed');
mysql_close($conn);
```

No Warning Now!?

Comment: Don't use mysql functions -.-

Comment: @Jeremy That's not a terribly helpful comment. I doubt he's using the `mysql` library out of spite, he probably just doesn't know there's any reason not to. At the very least [link to some resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1) and help him learn.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I got lazy, though you're right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The behaviour of the or operator in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213283/the-behaviour-of-the-or-operator-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`&&` and `||` are [logical operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) -- they're for Boolean conditional statements. As @towr and @ChrisHayes point you can use `and` and `or` in place of the `&&` and `||` syntax, albeit at a lower precedence than most other operators.

`or` in this context, however, is completely different -- it's part of the [control flow (see section 2.5.7: exit and return)](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/weblinux2/php/ch02_05.htm).

Boolean condition:

```
if ($foo == $bar || $bar != $bob)
```

Control flow:

```
mysql etc... or die();
```

You're receiving the error "PHP Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource..." because you're not actually writing correct syntax, thus breaking your `mysql_connect` statement.

Comment: Best answer but should address precedence even though the post doesn't ask about it and mentioning precedence wouldn't be a direct answer to the question.

Comment: According the the documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php `or` and `and` are also just logical operators, but they have difference precedence than `||` and `&&`.

Comment: Also, could you cite your sources?

Comment: Deleted my own answer for being somewhat misleading, but I think @towr's point needs to be addressed more prominently here. `and` and `or` are *not* part of the control flow, they're simply short-circuiting logical operators which work at a lower precedence than most other operators.

Comment: @ChrisHayes agreed - not sure why I included `and` in there in the first place.

Comment: You _can_ also do the same using `||`, to wit `($conn = mysql_connect(...) ) || die(":(")` So, `or` is not special with regards to flow control, though it's easier to use in this context. But I think for a complete answer, it should be pointed out what both statements actually assign to $conn.

Comment: The only difference between `||` and `or` is precedence. This difference in precedence has the effect of having a different outcome of `$foo = $bar || $baz` vs. `$foo = $bar or $baz`. `or` has in no way anything to do with "control flow".

Answer (score 5):

`and` and `or` have <s>higher</s> lower precedence than `&&` and `||`. To be more exact `&&` and `||` have higher precedence than assignment operator ( `=` ) while `and` and `or` have lower.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Usually it doesn't make a difference, but there are cases when not knowing about this difference can cause some unexpected behaviour. See examples here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

**EDIT(suggested by @towr):**

Applied to the question at hand, this means that in the first case we assign to `$conn` the value  `mysql_connect(....) || die('....'),`because `||` has a higher precendence than `=`. The problem here is that `$conn` now is a boolean, and not a resource.

In the second case we `OR` the expressions `$conn = mysql_connect(....)`  and  `die('....'),` because `=` has a higher precendence than `OR`. We do nothing with the boolean value, and `$conn` is simply the resource we assigned to it in the first expression (if it didn't fail).

Comment: @Jeremy It does, because this means 
`$foo = $a || $b` equals `$foo = ($a || $b`)  equals `$foo = ($a or $b`) whereas `$foo = $a or $b` equals `($foo = $a) || $b` equals (`$foo = $a) or $b`

Comment: Hmm... so apply this to the OP's question. How does it answer it?

Comment: @Aks There you go. +1